# Is there a way to have something similar to Cygwin on Mac?

Tags: macos, terminal, printing

I'm a web developer using a MacBook Pro running OS X 10.9.3.

Before I started developing in a Mac, I used Cygwin on a Windows machine to see what was happening behind the scene on my web application. I had a Logging system built in PHP which created log files with all the content of the variables I wanted to debug.

Basically, this Logging system creates another PHP file with all the debug needed and through Cygwin, every time I refreshed my web application in the browser it would refresh itself synchronously and outputted a new print with all my recent code updates.

I've searched everywhere but didn't find any close solution.
The one I'm using right now is using the terminal and writhing:

```
cat /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/BO_V2/data/logs/log-2014-07-10.php
```

But it is not automatic and I have to press <kbd>↑</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> every time I want to see what the log file has to show.

On OS X, is there a way to have Terminal or another application refresh the print from my log file every time I refresh my browser window (Chrome, Firefox or Safari)?

Comment: The command you want is tail with the -f parameter. However this is they way to do it in Cygwin anyway. Cygwin allows the use of Unix commands on Windows - All these command are already in OSX

Comment: I've already tried that but it only returns the last 10 lines of code counting from the bottom. The thing about cygwin was it automatic refresh witch saved me tones of time by the end of each project

Comment: What command in cygwin? `tail -f filename` works on all the Unix systems I have used as well as Cygwin

Answer (score 25, accepted):

- On windows, the Cygwin is a Unix-like environment.
- OS X (now macOS) is full on UNIX, so there is no need for any additions to get these unix tools.

Open Terminal.app and start with [manual pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page).

The `more` and `tail -f` commands are typical unix commands to page, search, and watch a log file.

For your example, the [tail](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tail.1.html) command to watch your log file is:

```
tail -f /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/BO_V2/data/logs/log-2014-07-10.php
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming it's the same as on Linux, you could also use:

```
less /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/BO_V2/data/logs/log-2014-07-10.php
```

Then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to have it tail automatically, or just <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to go to the end of file.

Comment: `more` is already `less` on OS X / darwin and the shift F/G commands work as advertised.